# Is it possible to remove a selection box around a path?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, path

I'm trying to wrap my head around how paths and selection boxes work in illustrator.

I created a half-ellipse using the ellipsis tool in a layer on top of another circle. The left part of this half-ellipse is showing the circle underneath it but the circle is hidden on the right side of the half-ellipse. Here is an image of what I am describing.

[image]

I want to show the circle on the right side of the half-ellipse but the selection box is preventing that. How can I either remove the selection box or close the path so the circle shows up on the right side of the half-ellipse?

Bonus: How can I hide the circle on the left side of the half-ellipse (opposite of what is in this picture)?

Here is a link to the .ai file: [Link to File](https://cl.ly/1x2Z3w0W3H3W)

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: +1 for complete clear details.  Welcome to the site, I hope you stick around!

Comment: That's so nice of you! Thanks for the warm welcome :)

Comment: Sure!  :)  Also have a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and the [site tour](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour).  I'd love to know whether my answer worked for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your half-ellipse is "filled" with white.  You can see that on the left hand side of your screenshot.

Just below the white "fill" square (in the left sidebar) and the black "stroke" square, there is a box with a red slash for "no color."  Click that to convert your selected object (half ellipse) to "no fill."

Comment: Ok, that was the issue! A little embarrassing because i have basic knowledge of stroke and fill. Thanks.